# how to use JSON/jQuery to fetch all videos from a Youtube Channel using YouTbe v3 data API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, youtube, youtube-data-api

Can someone please help me getting videos from a youtube Channel?

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Uploads</title>    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1> Videos </h1>
        <ul id="results"></ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and below is my JavaScript:

```
var channelName = 'UCcPHkNcLFjenlxtMxEw_YZQ';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels",{
            part: 'contentDetails',
            forUsername: channelName,
            key: 'API Key'},
            function(data){
                $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
                    console.log(item);
                    pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
                    getVids(pid);
                })
            }
    );
    function getVids(pid){
        $.get(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",{
                part: 'snippet',
                maxResults: 10,
                playlistId: pid,
                key: 'API Key'},
                function(data){
                    var output;
                    $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
                        console.log(item);
                        videTitle = item.snippet.title;
                        //videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
                        output = '<li>'+videTitle+'</li>';
                        console.log(output);
                        //$('#results').append(output);
                    })
                }

        );

    }
});
```

I need guidance in order to get videos from YouTube Channel to a webpage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not get any error in my console too.

Comment: What is the response data? Is it an Object? Could you show us too?
Does it has an *result* property?

Comment: Can you console log the data and see whether you got the response or not?

Comment: add a `fail()` handler also. If something doesn't work obvious thing is to add error handling to it. You haven't provided the least bit of debugging information. Can also inspect actual request in browser dev tools network for clues

Comment: I do not get anything in my console log.  It is totally blank

Comment: How about checking the responses under Network console tab?Any errors?

Comment: The network console shows 304